# Is the cotangent bundle to $P^2$ a toric variety?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, toric-geometry

Is the cotangent bundle to the complex projective plane, $T^* P^2$, a toric variety?
More generally, is there a criterion for when a vector bundle over a toric variety is a toric variety?

For example, in this related question [When are vector bundles on toric varieties also toric varieties?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1125255/when-are-vector-bundles-on-toric-varieties-also-toric-varieties) it is suggested that if it splits, then it is a toric variety.

Comment: The question you cited refers to a thesis, which leads to Oda's Tata Lectures on Torus Embeddings. He doesn't explain why, but he seems to imply that the toric structure lifts to a vector bundle if and only if it splits (my suspicion is that this has something to do with the theory of linearizations of line bundles that comes up in GIT). Since the cotangent bundle of $P^2$ does not split, it is presumably not a toric variety.

Comment: @TabesBridges Thanks, that confirms my intuition. Can you confirm we are both referring to the remark where Oda speaks about 'torus embedding unless totally decomposable' and that this means 'toric variety iff it splits'?

Comment: I am referring to that passage. "Torus embedding" is the old term for toric variety, and a quick Google search suggests that "totally decomposable" just means splits into direct sum of line bundles.