# When is the total space of a vector bundle over $\mathbb{C}P^{1}$ a toric variety?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, vector-bundles

Consider a vector bundle $\pi:E\to\mathbb{C}P^{1}$. We know that we can make the decomposition
$$
E=\mathcal{O}(q_{1})\oplus\mathcal{O}(q_{2})\oplus\cdots\oplus\mathcal{O}(q_{n})
\text{ , }
q_{i}\in\mathbb{Z}
$$
I am wondering when the total space of this vector bundle can be described as a toric variety.

An answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1125255/when-are-vector-bundles-on-toric-varieties-also-toric-varieties) question claims without reference or proof that the total space is simply the weighted projective space $\mathbb{P}(q_{1},q_{2},\cdots,q_{n})$, which is clearly a toric variety. However to my knowledge, weighted projective spaces are only defined for strictly positve weights, which is not necessarily the case for the weights appearing in $E$.

With this in mind, I guess my quesiton boils down to the following sub-questions.

1. Is there a good notion of weighted projective space when some of the weights are negative or zero?
2. Is the total space of $E$ such a weighted projective space, or does this only hold for positive weights?
3. If yes, how can I see that the total space of $E$ is such a weighted projective space?

Comment: The linked answer is referring to the total space of the projectivization of that vector bundle, but your question doesn't mention the projectivization. Could you clarify whether you meant to ask about the projectivization?

Comment: I didn't realise that the linked answer was refering to the projectivisation only. My primary interest is in the vector bundle itself, but anything that can be said about the projectivisation is interesting as well.

Comment: Regarding negative $q_i$: If you are only interested in the projectivization, you can always assume that the $q_i$ are positive by tensoring with a high enough power of $\mathcal O(1)$.

Comment: but what about the vector bundle itself, not its projectivization? is e.g. O(-3)+O(1)->P^1 a toric variety?